# How to log into facebook using libCurl/C++?

Tags: c++, post, curl, libcurl, facebook-login

Just as the title suggests, I am trying to log into Facebook using libCurl/C++.

I'm new to both libCurl and C/C++

I can download the home page just fine, but when I try to log in, I run into issues.

Here is my attempt at a login function.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
string htmlFromLoginPage;

void login() {
    string text(htmlFromLoginPage);

    // Gets all input values in the login form and converts the names/values into arguments
    boost::regex regex("<input[^<]*name=\"([^\"]*)\"[^<]*value=\"([^\"]*)\"[^<]*>");

    // Captures groups 1 and 2 (input name and value respectively)
    const int subs[] = {1, 2};
    boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(), regex, subs);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator end;

    string params;
    bool odd = true;
    while (iter != end) {
        string token = *iter;
        params += s;
        if (odd)            token += "=";
        else                token += "&";
        if (s == "email")   token += "john.doe@gmail.com&pass=supersecretpass";
        odd = !odd;
        params += token;
    }
    // By now the parameters look good (from what I can tell)
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        // Clear login page html to prepare for form response html (write function just appends to this string)
        htmlFromLoginPage.clear();

        // Set up options and attempt to submit POST form
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&amp;next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhome.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_write);

        // Convert params to url encoded string (takes care of special chars)
        params = curl_easy_escape(curl, params.c_str(), 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, params.c_str());
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);      
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "Facebook curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
         curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        // See what the response page looks like
        ofstream out("output.html");
        out << "Using params: \n" << params << "\n";
        out << html;
        out.close();
    }
}
```

It only grabs the login page. It doesn't grab the new home page.

Comment: Hey here is my suggestion: use Python. It's so easy and clean. C/C++ takes way too much effort and I doubt it is much more efficient.